# Storing localStorage data in an array

Tags: arrays, json, html, local-storage

I am storing the `response` in `localStorage` and retrieving it's value. My `response` is in `json` format. The `response` changes depending on the user input. A sample `response` is:

```
      {
       "Name": "robert",
       "Number": "555-555-1234"
      }
```

I am storing and retrieving and displaying `response` as:

```
     localStorage.setItem("response", JSON.stringify(response));
     var myResponse = localStorage.getItem("response");
     console.log(myResponse);
```

Currently it is displaying me the most current `response` and all the previous `response` are getting replaced. How can I store the `response` in an `array` so that I can store all the `response` that I get. Something like:

```
  [ 
   {
       "Name": "robert",
       "Number": "555-555-1234"
   },
   {
       "Name": "john",
       "Number": "555-555-9999 Ext. 123"
   },
   {
       "Name": "albert",
       "Number": "555-555-8765"
   },
   {
       "Name": "jhony",
       "Number": "555-555-3098"
   },
   .
   .

 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Store and retrieve a serialized array instead:

```
// Retrieving
var responses = JSON.parse(localStorage.responses || "null") || [];

// Adding a response
responses.push(response);

// Saving the array
localStorage.responses = JSON.stringify(responses);
```

Or using `getItem`/`setItem`, if you prefer:

```
// Retrieving
var responses = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("responses") || "null") || [];

// Adding a response
responses.push(response);

// Saving the array
localStorage.setItem("responses", JSON.stringify(responses));
```

---

The idiom

```
var responses = JSON.parse(localStorage.responses || "null") || [];
```

could probably use some explaining:

1. If we try to retrieve something that doesn't exist in local storage, we get back `null`. JavaScript has a [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html): Rather than returning a boolean value, it returns the left-hand argument if that argument is truthy, and its right-hand argument otherwise. So `localStorage.responses || "null"` will be the string from local storage, or if there isn't one, the string `"null"`.
2. We then parse the result, which is either a serialized array we stored earlier, or the string `"null"`. Although the string `"null"` wouldn't be a valid JSON document, it *is* a valid JSON *fragment*, and `JSON.parse` is documented to accept fragments. So the result of the parsing is either the array we stored previously, or `null`.
3. Then we use the curiously-powerful `||` operator again to choose between the deserialized result and a blank array (`[]`). So if we deserialized `null`, we'll choose `[]`; if we deserialized an array, we'll get that.

---

Here's a complete working example; all it does is put some UI around the fundamental operations above: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/AFIWAPIy/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/AFIWAPIy/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Complete Example</title>
  <style>
    .response {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <input type="text" id="responseInput">
  <input type="button" id="addResponse" value="Add">
  <script>
    (function() {
      // Get the responses (if any) or an empty array
      var responses = loadResponses();

      // Show the existing responses
      var container = $("#container");
      $.each(responses, function(index, response) {
        showResponse(response);
      });

      // Wait for user to add new ones
      var responseInput = $("#responseInput");
      responseInput.focus();
      $("#addResponse").click(function() {
        var text = $.trim(responseInput.val()),
            response = {
              text: text,
              id:   +new Date()
            };
        if (text) {
          responses.push(response);
          showResponse(response);
          saveResponses();
          responseInput.val("").focus();
        }
      });

      // Delete responses on click
      container.on("click", ".response", function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            id = parseInt($this.attr("data-id"), 10),
            index;
        $this.remove();
        if (id) {
          for (index = 0; index < responses.length; ++index) {
            if (responses[index].id === id) {
              responses.splice(index, 1);
              saveResponses();
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      });

      function loadResponses() {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.responses || "null") || [];
      }

      function saveResponses() {
        localStorage.responses = JSON.stringify(responses);
      }

      function showResponse(response) {
        $("<div>")
          .addClass("response")
          .text(response.text)
          .attr("data-id", response.id)
          .appendTo(container);
      };
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are telling first to `get` the `item` and then to `set` it?

Comment: @user2567857: I'm just showing the three operations that you would typically want to do, not necessarily saying you'd do them one right after another like that. I'd probably grab the array on page load, and then save it every time it changed.

Comment: Your method is showing error - `[object Object],[object Object]` if I do `document.write` to display results

Comment: @user2567857: Don't use `document.write`. Use a debugger. I've added a live example in case that helps. But the basic operations are exactly that: Very basic. The three one-liners in the first code block show how to do each basic operation.

Comment: @Crowder I think some problem is occuring between `response` and `responses`. Can you modify the code with `response` and `myResponse`, as I have shown in the question, else it is confusing me

Comment: @user2567857: I'm sorry, I've given you both the isolated answer and a complete example. You pretty much have to carry the ball from here. I used `responses` where you had used `response` because you said you wanted a list, so now there's more than one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44555/discussion-between-user2567857-and-t-j-crowder)

Comment: @user2567857: I don't do the chat thing if it's germane to the question or answer (I think it's one of SO's stupider things). But really, I think I've gone as far here as necessary. It's really up to you to take it from here.

Comment: what is your `response` then? where does it come from? I am talking about 3 lines of simple code

Comment: @user2567857: ***Look at the complete example.*** The response is whatever you want it to be. It's just an entry in the array. The code serializing/deserializing the array doesn't care what the entries are. In the complete example, I made them objects, because your code was using an object as a response and I figured you had a reason for doing that (and I wanted an `id` property so I could delete responses). But again, whatever you want it to be. Please take the time to thoroughly read the answer and example code.

Comment: @user2567857: The code answering the question clearly *does* work. I'm sorry you're having trouble adapting it to your code, but there's nothing I can do about that with the information available.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer - I don't have enough points for downvote

Comment: @user2567857: Not even answers to your own questions? Gosh, I'd think that would be a special case. Thanks for replying.